Stripe webhook with nextjs internationalization
So I am trying to add stripe webhook with basic Internationalization (i18n) Routing setup along with middleware file using NextJS 14.
// middlware.ts

import { NextRequest, NextResponse } from "next/server";
import Negotiator from "negotiator";
import { match } from "@formatjs/intl-localematcher";
let locales = ["en", "th"];
let defaultLocale = "en";
const PUBLIC_FILE = /\.(.*)$/;
const cookieName = "i18nlang";
// Get the preferred locale, similar to the above or using a library
function getLocale(request: NextRequest): string {
  // Get locale from cookie
  if (request.cookies.has(cookieName))
    return request.cookies.get(cookieName)!.value;
  // Get accept language from HTTP headers
  const acceptLang = request.headers.get("Accept-Language");
  if (!acceptLang) return defaultLocale;
  // Get match locale
  const headers = { "accept-language": acceptLang };
  const languages = new Negotiator({ headers }).languages();
  return match(languages, locales, defaultLocale);
}
export function middleware(request: NextRequest) {
  if (PUBLIC_FILE.test(request.nextUrl.pathname)) {
    return;
  }

  if (request.nextUrl.pathname.startsWith("/_next")) return NextResponse.next();

  // Check if there is any supported locale in the pathname

  const { pathname } = request.nextUrl;

  const pathnameHasLocale = locales.some(
    (locale) => pathname.startsWith(`/${locale}/`) || pathname === `/${locale}`
  );
  if (pathnameHasLocale) {
    return;
  }
  // Redirect if there is no locale
  const locale = getLocale(request);

  request.nextUrl.pathname = `/${locale}${pathname}`;
  // e.g. incoming request is /products
  // The new URL is now /en/products

  return NextResponse.redirect(request.nextUrl);
}
export const config = {
  matcher: [
    // Skip all internal paths (_next)
    "/((?!_next).*)",
    // Optional: only run on root (/) URL
    // '/'
  ],
};



When the checkout is completed, I am having redirection 307 issue and I am guessing it's because of my middleware is trying to redirect incoming webook request to another URL using internationlization code. So I added in middlware to ignore that specific route /api/webhooks to avoid redirection
  // start of middleware function
  if (request.nextUrl.pathname.startsWith("/api/webhooks"))
    return NextResponse.next();

it solved 307 issue but now I am having 405 method not allowed issue and I have no idea why. But when I change my endpoint URL in stripe dashboard from https://.../api/webhooks to https://.../en/api/webhooks it works.
Does it mean I have to create 2 webhooks with different endpoint URL (https://.../en/api/webhooks and https://.../th/api/webhooks) since I have 2 language in my system ? Or what can I add in middleware to fix the issue ?
UPDATE
It seems it doesn't make sense to create 2 webhooks with 2 different url for the same checkout process. For now I keep only 1 webhook and set the endpoint URL as https://.../en/api/webhooks as it has no issue with /th route as well.
